# I am having a problem displaying the top and side navigation menus using bootstrap 4 default code provided on the MDB webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

```js
// function to display loader before displaying page content
var myVar;

function displayLoader() {
  myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 3000);
}

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
}
// side navigation initialized
$(document).ready(function() {
  // SideNav Button Initialization
  $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
  // SideNav Scrollbar Initialization
  var sideNavScrollbar = document.querySelector('.custom-scrollbar');
  var ps = new PerfectScrollbar(sideNavScrollbar);
});

// SideNav Initialization
$(".button-collapse").sideNav();
```

```css
#loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  color: #4CAF50;
}

#myDiv {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.double-nav .breadcrumb-dn {
  color: #fff;
}

.side-nav.wide.slim .sn-ad-avatar-wrapper a span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.min.js">
</script>
<script src="dashboardjs.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesdashboard.css">


<head>
  <title>Dashboard</title>
</head>



<body class="hidden-sn grey-skin" onload="displayLoader()">

  <div class="spinner-grow" role="status" id="loader">
    <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
  </div>
  <div style="display: none;" " id="myDiv " class="animate-bottom ">
                

              <!--Double navigation-->
              <header>
                <!-- Sidebar navigation -->
                <div id="slide-out " class="side-nav sn-bg-4 ">
                  <ul class="custom-scrollbar ">
                    <!-- Logo -->
                    <li>
                      <div class="logo-wrapper waves-light ">
                        <a href="# "><img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/logo/mdb-transparent.png " class="img-fluid flex-center "></a>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                    <!--/. Logo -->
                    <!--Social-->
                    <li>
                      <ul class="social ">
                        <li><a href="# " class="icons-sm fb-ic "><i class="fab fa-facebook "> </i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="# " class="icons-sm pin-ic "><i class="fab fa-pinterest "> </i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="# " class="icons-sm gplus-ic "><i class="fab fa-google-plus "> </i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="# " class="icons-sm tw-ic "><i class="fab fa-twitter "> </i></a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <!--/Social-->
                    <!--Search Form-->
                    <li>
                      <form class="search-form " role="search ">
                        <div class="form-group md-form mt-0 pt-1 waves-light ">
                          <input type="text " class="form-control " placeholder="Search ">
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </li>
                    <!--/.Search Form-->
                    <!-- Side navigation links -->
                    <li>
                      <ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion ">
                        <li><a class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r "><i class="fas fa-chevron-right "></i> Submit
                            blog<i class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon "></i></a>
                          <div class="collapsible-body ">
                            <ul>
                              <li><a href="# " class="waves-effect ">Submit listing</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="# " class="waves-effect ">Registration form</a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r "><i class="far fa-hand-pointer "></i>
                            Instruction<i class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon "></i></a>
                          <div class="collapsible-body ">
                            <ul>
                              <li><a href="# " class="waves-effect ">For bloggers</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="# " class="waves-effect ">For authors</a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r "><i class="far fa-eye "></i> About<i class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon "></i></a>
                          <div class="collapsible-body ">
                            <ul>
                              <li><a href="# " class="waves-effect ">Introduction</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="# " class="waves-effect ">Monthly meetings</a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r "><i class="far fa-envelope "></i> Contact me<i
                              class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon "></i></a>
                          <div class="collapsible-body ">
                            <ul>
                              <li><a href="# " class="waves-effect ">FAQ</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="# " class="waves-effect ">Write a message</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="# " class="waves-effect ">FAQ</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="# " class="waves-effect ">Write a message</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="# " class="waves-effect ">FAQ</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="# " class="waves-effect ">Write a message</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="# " class="waves-effect ">FAQ</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="# " class="waves-effect ">Write a message</a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="collapsible-header waves-effect " href="# "><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt "></i>Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a class="collapsible-header waves-effect " href="# "><i class="fas fa-newspaper "></i>News</a></li>
                        <li><a class="collapsible-header waves-effect " href="# "><i class="fas fa-desktop "></i>Magazine</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <!--/. Side navigation links -->
                  </ul>
                  <div class="sidenav-bg mask-strong "></div>
                </div>
                <!--/. Sidebar navigation -->
                <!-- Navbar -->
                <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-expand-lg double-nav ">
                  <!-- SideNav slide-out button -->
                  <div class="float-left ">
                    <a href="# " data-activates="slide-out " class="button-collapse "><i class="fa fa-bars "></i></a>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Breadcrumb-->
                  <div class="breadcrumb-dn mr-auto ">
                    <p>Material Design for Bootstrap</p>
                  </div>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-flex-icons ml-auto ">
                    <li class="nav-item ">
                      <a class="nav-link "><i class="fa fa-envelope "></i> <span class="clearfix d-none d-sm-inline-block ">Contact</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item ">
                      <a class="nav-link "><i class="fa fa-comments-o "></i> <span class="clearfix d-none d-sm-inline-block ">Support</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item ">
                      <a class="nav-link "><i class="fa fa-user "></i> <span class="clearfix d-none d-sm-inline-block ">Account</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
                      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle " href="# " id="navbarDropdownMenuLink " data-toggle="dropdown "
                        aria-haspopup="true " aria-expanded="false ">
                        Dropdown
                      </a>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right " aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink ">
                        <a class="dropdown-item " href="# ">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item " href="# ">Another action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item " href="# ">Something else here</a>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </nav>
                <!-- /.Navbar -->
              </header>
              <!--/.Double navigation-->
            
              <!--Main Layout-->
              <main>
                <div class="container-fluid mt-5 ">
                  <h2>Advanced Double Navigation with a hidden SideNav under fixed Navbar:</h2>
                  <br>
                  <h5>1. Hidden side menu. Click "hamburger " icon in the top left corner to open it</h5>
                  <h5>2. Fixed Navbar. It will always stay visible on the top, even when you scroll down.</h5>
                  <div style="height: 2000px "></div>
                </div>
              </main>
              <!--Main Layout-->
            
            </body>
</html>
```

Both navigation bars aren't displaying correctly although I have used the same code provided in the link below:
https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/navigation/compositions/ 
in the "Double Navigation with slim sidenav and fixed navbar" section, and I don't know why I don't get the same as the live preview output, I don't know also if the code provided does need anymore styling or if it could be used as it is provided.

Comment: Can you specify your problem? In what way does the navigation bars differ from the expected output?

Comment: The following code should display a fixed side navigation bar on the left of the screen and a fixed top navigation bar, when I run the code the side navigation is displayed in the middle of the page and the layout is not organized properly.

Comment: Ok now it's more clear. Can you make a functional Codepen or JSFiddle example please?